# Unable to locate images folder in Visual web developer

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

i am doing some basic exercises for learning  c# in Visual web developer  , i have added my images folder in my project folder but problem is that when i try to import and  add this header to my home page image is not visible there  , this is my     **Header.ascx**

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
<img src="../images/bookshelf.jpg" alt="The night owl" 
    style="height: 215px; width: 802px" />
</asp:Panel>
```

1- Now in ascs file design view this visible in design view but when i drag n drop this file to my home page then this image is never there

2- Why image's path is `like this  src="../image`  while this is directly in my project folder

Please help me with it i am really stuck  on such easy  work

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the image SRC to ~/ instead of ../

Comment: that could work if you add runat="server". <img runat="server" src="~/images/bookshelf.jpg" alt ...